# Device not recognize by new update of android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently updated Android studio to version 2.1.3, and I'm having issues with my kindle fire. The kindle is not being recognize by Android. It is not listed under "connected devices". The problem started when I decided to install android canary 2.2.c. When it started giving me issues I decided to downgrade to a stable update, but the problem still remains. My kindle also updated recently, so I don't know if that can affect. My kindle  is using Fire OS 5.3.1 system.

Any ideas of what could it be? or how to solve it?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your device is (not) recognized by `adb`. Adb is part of the Android SDK, not of Android Studio. Therefore the update of Android Studio should not be the problem. Usually adb has just some internal problems. Restarting adb via `adb kill-server` should solve that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried adb kill-server and then adb reconnect, but stil no luck.

Comment: I also tried adb start-server, and reinstalling kindle and google usb drivers in the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was following the instructions here for enabling ADB to see the kindle fire: https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/resources/development-tools/ide-tools/tech-docs/05-setting-up-your-kindle-fire-tablet-for-testing

My kindle fire recently updated as well, and for some reason it reset the configuration to disable ADB access. I just went to settings -> Device Options-> Developer Options -> Enable ADB. Developer Options might be hidden in the Kindle Fire just tap seven times the serial number, and it should pop up.